# Problem with QMainWindow +QGraphicsView and more than one QGLWidget

Tags: qt

I have a problem in my Qt Application. I have a QMainWindow with a QGraphicsScene and a QGLWidget as viewport.

The problem comes when I want to show another QGLWidget with other OpenGL information (for example, the general view and another window with the Top view). 
In this case, the two windows don't work good and have problems with the transformation Matrix in OpenGL.
I try to use a shared widget (my first QGLWidget) and have the same context, but it fails anyway.

Any idea?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This will be pretty difficult to without code. As a guess, perhaps you're not [resetting your matrix operations](http://www.opengl.org/resources/features/KilgardTechniques/oglpitfall/) to a known state before using them (see part 3 of the link)?